# Can vegan diets have a positive effect on people with diabetes?

Tags: veganism, health, nutrition, therapeutic-diet

I'm wondering whether a diet rich in plant foods, such as a vegan diet, can have a positive impact on people with diabetes and/or people with pre-diabetes, the condition in which blood glucose levels are higher than normal but not high enough to be classified as full-blown diabetes.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, definitely.**

There are several investigations assessing this issue. In several clinical trials ([1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16873779), [2](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/early/2009/04/01/ajcn.2009.26736H.short)) Dr. Barnard has prooved that a low-fat vegan diet can improve serum values of **HbA1c** and requirements for medication of patients affected by type 2 diabetes. The same studies found significant improvements in **plasma lipids** (LDL and total cholesterols), that show decrease of risk factors for cardiovascular disease, often a complication of diabetes and metabolic disorders.

Additionally, clinical trials show that vegan and vegetarian diets promote **weight loss** ([3](http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/9863851), [4](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0002934305002792), [5](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19506174)) and improved **insulin sensitivity**([4](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0002934305002792), [5](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19506174)) being these two important risk factors for type 2 diabetes ([6](http://www.webmd.com/diabetes/risk-factors-for-diabetes)).

The reasons of the effectiveness must be found in the fact -among others- that vegetarians and vegans eat less quantities of **total fats**, **saturated fats** and highers amounts of **fiber** and show lower **BMI** ([7](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19562864)).