# How quickly does cholesterol decrease when on a vegan diet?

Tags: veganism, cholesterol

Vegan diet reduces blood cholesterol <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veganism#Health_effects),[2](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/280/115),[3](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/75/115)</sup>. However, **how does cholesterol decrease with time?** What I'm looking for is a sort of graph where X = days or weeks, and Y = cholesterol level.

Comment: Sounds like a good research project

Comment: Just an addend: the sources you have linked to claim that behavior under vegan diets, not vegan diet per se, promote cholesterol disease. If one becomes vegan and starts living on fried potatoes, one's cholesterol won't improve.

Comment: I modified the title slightly by changing "How" to "How quickly" -- I hope that's okay. It sounds like you're asking about how cholesterol levels change over time, not asking about the specific biological mechanisms that result in lower cholesterol.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any studies directly measuring this; however some information is available in related studies.

I found the following studies on cholesterol turnover in humans.

1. [Distribution and turnover of cholesterol in humans](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC322312/)
2. [Cholesterol turnover in human plasma lipoproteins: studies with stable and radioactive isotopes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6954844)

I found this review of cholesterol lowering therapies. It has some data on vegans under placebo, but none on a vegan diet as treatment.

3. [The Interpretation of Cholesterol Balance Derived Synthesis Data and Surrogate Noncholesterol Plasma Markers for Cholesterol Synthesis under Lipid Lowering Therapies](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/cholesterol/2017/5046294/)

**Some relevant info**

The following graph from [1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC322312/) shows the lifetime of an injected dose of cholesterol in the body. This might be an indication of how long consumed cholesterol will stay in your body, but can not be taken as an indicator of total cholesterol levels. Total cholesterol levels are also affected by cholesterol synthesis and excretion which is regulated by the body.

[image: Cholesterol injection time curve]